# Email font size changing when content changes

Tags: html, css, email

I'm running into this issue where my email's font size will change depending on what the content shows, for example here this simple example has an item with and without an extra TD in one of the rows, which completely changes the look of the email from one email to the other.

Here's the whole email code for the case where we have an item with an `end date` and a `result` column:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
   <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
    <title>HTML Email Template Boilerplate</title>
   <style type="text/css">
      table {
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

      td {
         padding: 0;
      }

      img {
         border: 0;
      }

      a {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #2c2c2c;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 699.98px) {
         td.two-column-header {
            width: 95px !important;
            max-width: 95px !important;
            min-width: 95px !important;
         }       

         img.two-col-img {
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
         }
      }
      /*@media screen and (max-width: 399.98px) {
         
      }*/
      

      :root {
         color-scheme: light dark;
         supported-color-schemes: light dark;
      }

      .human-reference {
         background-color:#f0f0f0;
         color:#0f0f0f;
      }    

      .badge-red {
         background-color: #dc2626; 
         color: #ffffff;
      }

      .service {
         background-color:#DDE0E1;
         color:#0f0f0f;
      }

   </style>
   
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    
</head>
<body style="Margin:0;padding:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#dde0e1;">

   <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <style type="text/css">
         body {background-color:#dde0e1!important;}
         body, table, td, p, a {font-family: Calibri, sans-serif !important;}
      </style>
   <![endif]-->

   <center style="width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;background-color:#dde0e1;padding-bottom: 40px;">
      <div style="max-width: 1250px;background-color: #fafafa;box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);">

         <!-- Preheader -->
         <div style="font-size: 0px;color: #fafafa;line-height: 1px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;display: none;max-width: 0px;max-height: 0px;opacity: 0;overflow: hidden;mso-hide:all;">
            <!-- latest update -->
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum porro tenetur ratione labore perferendis iste nesciunt temporibus maxime earum ut.
         </div>
         <!-- End Preheader -->
      

         <table align="center" style="border-spacing:0;color:#0f0f0f;font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif, Calibri, Helvetica;background-color: #fafafa;Margin:0;padding:0;width: 100%;max-width: 1250px;" role="presentation">



<!-- SECTION ONE -->
            <tr>
               <td class="section-header" style="padding: 7px 15px; background-color: #FCD9A4; color: #0f0f0f; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
                  Lorem
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 15px;">
                           <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;" role="presentation"> 
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="two-column-header" width="90" style="padding-right: 10px; width: 90px; max-width:90px; min-width:90px; border-spacing:0; vertical-align: top;">
                                    <table width="100%" style="width: 100%; border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">  
                                       <tr>
                                          <td style="text-align: right; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                             <span class="badge-red" style="font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; padding: 2px 6px; border-radius: 2px; display: inline-block; mso-padding-alt: 0;">
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                <i style="letter-spacing: 3px; mso-text-raise: 1pt;">&nbsp;</i>
                                                <![endif]-->
                                                LOREM
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                <i style="letter-spacing: 3px; mso-text-raise: -1pt;">&nbsp;</i>
                                                <![endif]-->
                                             </span>
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td style="text-align: right; padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                             <span class="human-reference" style="margin: 0; font-weight:bold;padding: 0 4px; margin-top: 0;text-transform:uppercase;line-height: 20px;border-radius: 2px;display: inline-block;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                <i style="letter-spacing: 3px; mso-text-raise: 1pt;">&nbsp;</i>
                                                <![endif]-->
                                                001
                                                <!--[if mso]>
                                                <i style="letter-spacing: 3px; mso-text-raise: -1pt;">&nbsp;</i>
                                                <![endif]-->
                                             </span>
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>

                                 <td style="padding-right: 10px;">
                                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">  
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>
                                             <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td style="width: 33%; text-align: left;padding-right: 20px;">
                                                      <span style="margin: 0;font-weight:bold;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                                                         Start | 
                                                      </span>
                                                      <span  style="margin: 0;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                                                         2000-01-01 | 00:00
                                                      </span>
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td style="width: 33%; text-align: left;padding-right: 20px;">
                                                      <span style="margin: 0;font-weight:bold;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                                                         End | 
                                                      </span>
                                                      <span  style="margin: 0;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                                                         2000-01-01 | 10:00
                                                      </span>
                                                   </td>
                                                   <td style="width: 33%; text-align: left;padding-right: 20px;">
                                                      <span style="margin: 0;font-weight:bold;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                                                         Results | 
                                                      </span>
                                                      <span style="margin: 0;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                                                         Lorem, ipsum dolor.
                                                      </span>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </table>
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>

                                       <tr>
                                          <td style="padding: 6px 0 20px 0;  line-height: 20px;">
                                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim vel necessitatibus eaque architecto, accusantium tenetur.
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>

                                       <tr>
                                          <td>
                                             <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td>
                                                         <!--[if mso]>
                                                         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" role="presentation" style="Margin: 0px 0px 2px 0px;">
                                                         <tr>
                                                         <td border="0">
                                                         <![endif]-->
                                                         <span class="service" style="margin: 0;margin-bottom:2px;Margin: 0 0 2px 0;padding: 0 4px;line-height: 20px;border-radius: 2px;display: inline-block;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                                            <i style="letter-spacing: 2px; mso-text-raise: 1pt;">&nbsp;</i>
                                                            <![endif]-->
                                                            Service 01
                                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                                            <i style="letter-spacing: 2px; mso-text-raise: -1pt;">&nbsp;</i>
                                                            <![endif]--> 
                                                         </span>
                                                         <!--[if mso]>
                                                         </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         </table>
                                                         <![endif]-->

                                                         <!--[if mso]>
                                                         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" role="presentation" style="Margin: 0px 0px 2px 0px;">
                                                         <tr>
                                                         <td border="0">
                                                         <![endif]-->
                                                         <span class="service" style="margin: 0;margin-bottom:2px;Margin: 0 0 2px 0;padding: 0 4px;line-height: 20px;border-radius: 2px;display: inline-block;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                                            <i style="letter-spacing: 2px; mso-text-raise: 1pt;">&nbsp;</i>
                                                            <![endif]-->
                                                            Service 02
                                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                                            <i style="letter-spacing: 2px; mso-text-raise: -1pt;">&nbsp;</i>
                                                            <![endif]--> 
                                                         </span>
                                                         <!--[if mso]>
                                                         </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         </table>
                                                         <![endif]-->
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </table>
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr> 
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     
                     <tr>
                        <td class="separator" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #DDE0E1;"></td>
                     </tr>
                     
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
<!-- END SECTION ONE -->

<!-- FEEDBACK -->
            <tr>
               <td style="padding: 10px 0;">
                  <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0 10px; ">
                           <span>Was this email helpful? </span>
                           <a class="feedback-link" style="color: #0330CF; text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold;" target="_blank" href="mailto:lorem@ipsum.com?subject=[LOREM IPSUM] Mail Feedback">Send us your feedback</a>
                           <span style="margin-left: 2px;">so we can improve!</span>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
<!-- END FEEDBACK -->

         </table>

      
      </div>
   </center>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: item with results column]
[image: item without results column]

Our backend simply removes the `td` for the results if there are none. One thing I've been trying is to instead always have 3 columns and set each of them at 33% which works fine in desktop, but on mobile, it simply refuses to apply the width:

```
 <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">
    <tr>
       <td class="one-third" style="width: 33%; max-width: 33%; text-align: left; padding-right: 20px; background-color: red;">
          <span style="margin: 0;font-weight:bold;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
             Start | 
          </span>
          <span  style="margin: 0;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
             2000-01-01 | 00:00
          </span>
       </td>
       <td class="one-third" style="width: 33%; max-width: 33%; text-align: left; padding-right: 20px; background-color: blue;">
          <span style="margin: 0;font-weight:bold;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
             End | 
          </span>
          <span  style="margin: 0;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
             TBD
          </span>
       </td>
       <td class="one-third" style="width: 33%; max-width: 33%; text-align: left; padding-right: 20px; background-color: green;">
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

You can see when I apply some colors, the three "33%" columns just are completely ignored

[image: column width not working]